# Method that passes options to its object

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I'd like to take an object and pass a parameter to it and based on the parameter have a method that will pass settings to the parameter:

```
functionName( parameter , settings );
```

Or

```
functionName( parameter ).methodName( settings );
```

example: for my iPhone web app setup I do heavy('setup',{ icon: 'icon.png' }); and I want to move the second parameter to a method: heavy('setup').settings({ icon: 'icon.png' }); for my ease and learning...

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.  It will help if you give a more realistic example.

Comment: yep, question makes no sense.

Comment: Like I have a function to setup my HTML page for an iPhone web app quickly but I have to type heavy('setup',{ icon: 'ico.png' }); and I'd like to move the second parameter to a method to make it a little easier for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
heavy = function() {
  var _settings;

  return {
    setup: function (settings){
      this._settings = settings;
    },

    getSetting: function (settingName) {
      if(this._settings[settingName])
      {              
        return this._settings[settingName];
      }
      return "Setting not found";
    }
  };
}();

heavy.setup({"icon":"myicon.png"});
alert(heavy.getSetting("icon"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have not given any decent details on what exactly you want to do , but from what I understand you need to return a common object (In most cases a class). The object that is returned needs to implement the method that you want to call as well.

The simplest example I can think of is the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library , they use a very similiar model

Comment: Yeah jQuery is where I got the idea but I can't really understand how they get it all to work...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean something  like this:

```
function lite(type){
  heavy(type, { icon: 'ico.png' });
}

//lite('setup')
```

or something like this

```
function getHeavy(obj){
  return function(type){
     heavy(type, obj);
  }
};

var icoFn = getHeavy({icon:'ico.png'});
icoFn('setup');
var poopFn = getHeavy({icon:'poop.png'});
poopFn('setup');
```